appendZoneId() vs appendZoneOrOffsetId() java DateTimeFormatterBuilder
I am not getting clarity on when to use appendZoneId() and when to use appendZoneOrOffsetId()
in Java's DateTimeFormatterBuilder.
In Java, the documentation says both append either ZoneId or OffsetId,  then what is the difference  between appendZoneId() and appendZoneOrOffsetId()?

The documentation for appendZoneOrOffsetId() says:

Note that this method is identical to appendZoneId() except in the mechanism used to obtain the zone.

The differences in the mechanism used to obtain the zone are as follows:

appendZoneId:
"the zone is obtained using a mechanism equivalent to querying the temporal with TemporalQueries.zoneId()"
appendZoneOrOffsetId:
"the zone is obtained using a mechanism equivalent to querying the temporal with TemporalQueries.zone()"

In practice, whether you will see a difference depends on what kind of datetime you are trying to format - whether it contains a zone id or just an offset. Consider the following code:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtfZ = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendZoneId().toFormatter();
    DateTimeFormatter dtfZO = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendZoneOrOffsetId().toFormatter();
    tryPrint(ZonedDateTime.now(), dtfZ, "appendZoneId");
    tryPrint(ZonedDateTime.now(), dtfZO, "appendZoneOrOffsetId");
    tryPrint(OffsetDateTime.now(), dtfZ, "appendZoneId");
    tryPrint(OffsetDateTime.now(), dtfZO, "appendZoneOrOffsetId");
}

private static void tryPrint(TemporalAccessor dt, DateTimeFormatter dtf, String description) {
    System.out.printf("Trying to format %s using %s:%n\t", dt, description);
    try {
        System.out.println(dtf.format(dt));
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

Output:
Trying to format 2024-09-24T13:08:10.042968898+01:00[Europe/London] using appendZoneId:
    Europe/London

Trying to format 2024-09-24T13:08:10.045608600+01:00[Europe/London] using appendZoneOrOffsetId:
    Europe/London

Trying to format 2024-09-24T13:08:10.046282182+01:00 using appendZoneId:
    java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to extract ZoneId from temporal 2024-09-24T13:08:10.046282182+01:00

Trying to format 2024-09-24T13:08:10.046858510+01:00 using appendZoneOrOffsetId:
    +01:00

As you can see, if you want to format a datetime with a zone region, then you can use either. But if you only have an offset instead of a region, then you need to use appendZoneOrOffsetId.
To complicate things further, there is a third method: appendZoneRegionId(). This behaves in a similar way to appendZoneId, except when you try to format a ZonedDateTime whose ZoneId is a ZoneOffset. A formatter with appendZoneId will happily append the offset if there is no region, whereas a formatter with appendZoneRegionId will throw an exception if the ZoneId is not a ZoneRegion:
DateTimeFormatter dtfZ = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendZoneId().toFormatter();
DateTimeFormatter dtfZR = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendZoneRegionId().toFormatter();

dtfZ.format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))); // ok
dtfZ.format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1)));      // ok

dtfZR.format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))); // ok
dtfZR.format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1)));      // exception!


Thank you for quick response,
then  can you explain appendZoneId() vs appendZoneRegionId() ?

@Mat I've updated my answer.
